# Removing 18 characters after a word on each line via Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I'm trying to figure out the regex I can use via Sublime Text to achieve the following for each line in a document:

Before:

```
<p begin="00:00:06.933" end="00:00:09.761">- Blah blah
```

After:

```
<p begin="00:00:06.933">- Blah blah
```

My thinking is a command that will match

end="

and then a replace to delete it along with the 18 characters in front.

But I'm absolutely new to regex and don't know how to do this.

Comment: `/\s+end="[^"]+"/`

Comment: @PranavCBalan, please write that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following regex :

```
/\s+end="[^"]+"/
```

Where `\s+` for matching the whitespace and `[^"]+` for combination anything other than `"`.

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/W1D4DD/2)

---

**FYI :** If the pattern only contains number and colon then you can use `[\d:]+` instead of `[^"]+`.